# Single word for "very centered around one opinion"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, british-english

What is a word for someone who is very centered around one opinion, and is reluctant to others? I keep going back to absent-minded or reluctant to change, but I know there is a word that is more suitable.

Comment: "opinionated"? https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Opinionated&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

Comment: [***bullheaded***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bullheaded) is a possible less formal alternative.

Comment: Dogmatic?  Stubborn?

Comment: What do you mean by "others"? Other *people* or other *ideas*? That is, are you talking about someone who wouldn't accept something *because* it came from someone else; or do they reject something because that *something* is different from some canonical idea, even if the alternative *something* was thought up by himself/herself?

Comment: other ideas; someone who is not prepared to allow people's ideas to change their own, thanks

Comment: Could you pelase think of a descriptive title though? Remember that the tite is what is shown on the main page.

Comment: **Pigheaded**.  (And I'm pretty sure this same question was asked about two days ago.)

Comment: "centered around one opinion"=to be monomaniacal about something

Comment: @gabby (1) What about other ideas that the same person subsequently thinks of? Is the person open to those? (2) *Why* is the person reluctant to accept other ideas?

Comment: I don't believe *absent-minded* is appropriate for the idea you are describing.  Absent-minded means inattentive, forgetful, or distracted.

Comment: Dogmatic, narrow-minded, stubborn and pig-headed are all good.

Answer (score 2):

Try [narrow-minded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrow-minded):

Definition:
*Not willing to accept opinions, beliefs, or behaviors that are unusual or different from your own.*

Examples:
*Her mother was narrow-minded about religion. He had a narrow-minded view of Japanese culture.*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're thinking of the word [egocentric](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/egocentric?s=t) or some of its synonyms. (Note the second definition...)

> 2.
>   having little or no regard for **interests**, **beliefs**, or **attitudes** other than one's own; self-centered:
>
> *an egocentric person; egocentric demands upon the time and patience of others.*

Comment: thank you - through its synonyms, I found OBSTINATE which seems to fit perfectly.

Comment: @gabby- I was going to offer *obstinate* as an answer, but you seem to have found it on your own.  If that is what you want, I invite you to answer your own question (with a link to the dictionary/ thesaurus that helped you) and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word **fanatic** for this use case, assuming a significant, unrelenting attachment to the belief or opinion in question.

noun
1.
a person with an extreme and uncritical enthusiasm or zeal, as in religion or politics.

adjective
2.
fanatical.